# Property '_id' does not exist on type Pick

Tags: mongodb, typescript, mongoose, next.js

I'm using Next.js and I'm trying to query MongoDB with TypeScript and mongoose, but I have a type error.

`types.d.ts`

```js
type dbPost = {
  _id: string
  user: {
    uid: string
    name: string
    avatar: string
  }
  post: {
    title: string
    description: string
    markdown: string
    slug: string
    createdAt: string
  }
}
```

```js
export const getSlugData = async (slug: string) => {
  await dbConnect()

  const data:
    | Pick<dbPost, '_id' | 'post' | 'user'>
    // The problem seems to be here with Pick[]
    | Pick<dbPost, '_id' | 'post' | 'user'>[]
    | null = await Post.findOne({ 'post.slug': slug }).lean().select('-__v')

  const post = {
    ...data,
    _id: `${data._id}`,
    // _id and createdAt are objects created by mongoose which can't be serialized.
    // They must be converted to a string
    post: {
      ...data.post,
      createdAt: `${data.post.createdAt}`,
    },
  }
  return post
}
```

I'm getting the following error:

```
Property '_id' does not exist on type 'Pick<dbPost, "_id" | "post" | "user"> | Pick<dbPost, "_id" | "post" | "user">[]'.
  Property '_id' does not exist on type 'Pick<dbPost, "_id" | "post" | "user">[]'.ts(2339)
```

What is it about `Pick<>[]` that I am doing wrong?

`package.json`

```json
  "dependencies": {
    "mongoose": "^5.10.6",
...
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@types/mongoose": "^5.7.36",
...
  }
```

[dbConnect()](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/blob/canary/examples/with-mongodb-mongoose/utils/dbConnect.js) is a function I took from the Next.js examples

Answer (score 1):

This is because you've told the compiler that `data` could be an array and in that case requires different accesses to singular objects.

`findOne` does not return an array, `findOne` only returns a `Record<string, T>` or `null`. You should remove the `Pick<dbPost, '_id' | 'post' | 'user'>[]` from your type union.

```
const data:
| Pick<dbPost, '_id' | 'post' | 'user'>
| null = await Post.findOne({ 'post.slug': slug }).lean().select('-__v')
```

Now `data` could still be `null` so you need to just make sure you aren't accessing properties on `null`. The whole function:

```
export const getSlugData = async (slug: string) => {
  await dbConnect()

   const data:
    | Pick<dbPost, '_id' | 'post' | 'user'>
    | null = await Post.findOne({ 'post.slug': slug }).lean().select('-__v')

   // first check if data is null
   const post = data && {
    ...data,
    _id: `${data._id}`,
    // _id and createdAt are objects created by mongoose which can't be serialized.
    // They must be converted to a string
      post: {
        ...data.post,
        createdAt: `${data.post.createdAt}`,
      },
    }
    return post
 }
```

To ensure type-correctness also make sure your `select` matches the fields in your `Pick<>`.

Comment: Correct, but when I use your solution the compiler still complains about the type union: `Type 'Pick<any, string | number | symbol> | Pick<any, string | number | symbol>[]' is not assignable to type 'Pick<dbPost, "_id" | "post" | "user">' Type 'Pick<any, string | number | symbol>[]' is missing the following properties from type 'Pick<dbPost, "_id" | "post" | "user">': _id, post, userts(2322)`

Comment: @Diego, perhaps that's because you also need to add `.exec()` to actually execute the query: `await Post.findOne({ 'post.slug': slug }).lean().select('-__v').exec()`

Comment: I tried that. It didn't change the error. I moved this function a .js file for now. I don't know much, but there could be an issue with the type declaration by mongoose. I'll come back to this later. Thanks.